# Why can the orbital quantom number $l$ take on half integer values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In Griffiths' "Introduction to quantum mechanics", the author shows in chapter 4 that the orbital quantum number $l$ can take on half integer numbers. This is shown using Dirac's lowering and raising operators on $L_z$. Applying the raising operator several times from $-L^2 = L_z$ until $L^2 = L_z$, l changes from $-l$ to $l$ in $N$ steps. Provided that $N$ is a positive integer it follows that $l$ is allowed to be any half integer. But I don't understand that last part, why do we assume that $N$ has to be a positive integer. If the raising operator raises the eigenvalue by $\hbar$, I thought that $N$ had to be a positive even number, but that would obviously only allow $l$ to take on integer values. Can someone help me understand why we make this assumption?

Comment: As an example, if you start at $m = -\hbar/2$ and raise $m$ by $\hbar$, then you get to $m = + \hbar /2$.

Comment: There’s confusion here: $l$ can only take *integer* values.  $j$ can be integer or half-integer.  Moreover, $L^2=L_z$ does not make sense.

Comment: I mean that the angular momentum lies completely in the -z direction, then we apply the raising operator until we reach the highest rung, which is when the angular momentum lies in the +z direction. Yes, you're right if you define j as the total angular momentum. Nevertheless, this is the way Griffiths writes in his book.